# How to setup lightsail VPC peering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

I set up VPC Peering `my_vpc` to `lightsail_vpc` in VPC Dashboard.

But it is waiting to be accepted.

How can I accept VPC peering?

The Lightsail's VPC User ID shown in the VPC Dashboard is different from my REAL User ID and cannot be accepted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-set-up-vpc-peering-with-aws-resources has a couple of steps to work through (I'm assuming you've looked through them?) and at the end says if it isn't working to contact AWS Support

Seems like the Default VPC in the region you are peering with is often the problem - https://serverfault.com/questions/818280/cant-establish-vpc-peering-connection-from-amazon-lightsail --> Have you confirmed you have a "default VPC" in the region? That there isn't a CIDR overlap between lightsail VPC and your default VPC?

Comment: Thank you for answer. The default vpc currently exists in that region. And the vpc trying to peer is also in the same region. CIDR also does not overlap. Is it normal to be automatically accepted when peering with lightsail VPC?

Comment: At the end of https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-set-up-vpc-peering-with-aws-resources it says "If it doesn't work, contact AWS Customer Support. https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home/" - sounds like you are at that point now?

Comment: "On the Basic Support Plan, you can create account and billing support cases and service limit increase requests, but you cannot create technical support cases."

Comment: From https://serverfault.com/questions/818280/cant-establish-vpc-peering-connection-from-amazon-lightsail it says: "Note that you don't need a paid support plan in order to request that AWS update your account as I've described above. You aren't actually asking for technical support. You can submit this as an account support request."

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and share the answer.

Comment: AWS was not very kind... "And in case if you want technical assistance then you can go ahead and opt in for any of the Premium Support plans.This would help you get in touch directly with our technical support engineers:"